# Why does DotNet XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema treat DateTimeOffset as a DateTime?

Tags: .net, xml, datetimeoffset

I have an XML element with value `2099-12-31T23:59:58.576+13:00` from a DateTimeOffset.

When I run `myDS.ReadXml(myStream, XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema)` I get `Specified cast is not valid.Couldn't store <2019-12-31 23:59:58> in MyColDTO Column.  Expected type is DateTimeOffset.`

The appended offset should clearly indicate a DateTimeOffset rather than a DateTime.

Why does DotNet (FW 4.6.2) incorrectly identify it?
Is there an easy way to fix it?

====Self contained vb.net Unit Test===

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub THC2398_ReadXml_Bug()
Dim ds1 As DataSet, ds2 As DataSet, dt1 As DataTable, dt2 As DataTable, dr As DataRow, dtoAt As DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-12-31T23:59:58.576+13:00")

Assert.AreEqual("v4.0.30319", GetType(String).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion, "Version check")
Assert.AreEqual("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", GetType(String).Assembly.FullName, "Version check")

ds1 = New DataSet("ds")
dt1 = New DataTable("dt")
ds1.Tables.Add(dt1)
dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MyColDTO", GetType(DateTimeOffset)))
dr = dt1.NewRow
dr("MyColDTO") = dtoAt
dt1.Rows.Add(dr)
Assert.AreEqual(1, dt1.Rows.Count)
Assert.AreEqual("DateTimeOffset", dt1.Rows(0)(0).GetType.Name)

Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New StringWriter, tr As TextReader
dt1.WriteXml(tw, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
System.Console.WriteLine(tw.ToString)

tr = New StringReader(tw.ToString)
ds2 = New DataSet("ds")
ds2.ReadXml(tr, XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema)
dt2 = ds2.Tables("dt")
Assert.AreEqual(1, dt2.Rows.Count)
'Assert.AreEqual("DateTimeOffset", dt2.Rows(0)(0).GetType.Name, "this was expected")
Assert.AreEqual("DateTime", dt2.Rows(0)(0).GetType.Name, "*BUG* WHAT?! how can you tell me that 2099-12-31T23:59:58.576+13:00 is a DateTime?")

For Each item As DataRow In dt2.Rows
    dr = dt1.NewRow
    Try
        dr.ItemArray = item.ItemArray
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        Assert.AreEqual("Specified cast is not valid.Couldn't store <2019-12-31 23:59:58> in MyColDTO Column.  Expected type is DateTimeOffset.", ex.Message, "Confirm that the bug is giving its bad message")
        Assert.Fail("This should not have happened")
    End Try
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr)
Next
End Sub
```

output from Console:

```
<ds>
  <dt>
    <MyColDTO>2019-12-31T23:59:58.576+13:00</MyColDTO>
  </dt>
</ds>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is .. because DataSets do not support DateTimeOffset [DataColumn.DataType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.6.2#System_Data_DataColumn_DataType). But .. SQL Server does [datetimeoffset (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Seems that Microsoft software is not compatible with itself.